# Passing combobox selected value to a dialog using ajaxlink

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I' trying to pass the dropDownList selected value to this Dialog.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

I tried adding another parameter to the ajaxlink, using `array('id'=>'showEventoDialog','tipoaux'=>$data["tipo"])`, or only `$data->tipo` but can't seem to do what I want.

I'm also trying to get the value via `$_GET` from the Dialog form.

Here's my form and the Dialog link within the form

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'tipo'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'tipo',Lookup::items('Teste')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'tipo'); ?>
```

...

```
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'eventoid'); ?>
  <div id="evento">
     <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'eventoid',CHtml::listData(Evento::model()->findAll(),'id', 'designacao'),array('prompt'=>'Escolha','class'=>'required')); ?>
     <?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(Yii::t('evento','Novo Evento'),$this->createUrl('evento/addnewcom'),array(
                                        'onclick'=>'$("#eventoDialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
                                        'update'=>'#eventoDialog'
                                        ),array('id'=>'showEventoDialog'));?>
      <div id="eventoDialog"></div>
   </div>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?
Plus will the solution work with any other type of value, like textfield or something else on my form, so I can pass the values to dialogs BEFORE the parent form is submitted.

Comment: Are you only need to paste the value of the dropdown in `<div id="eventoDialog"></div>`

Comment: I need to send the selected value on the dropDownList to the dialog window. I also need to know how to do this for any other value that is filled on a form so I can pass it to a dialog.

Comment: Dialog window aor dialog box..??Actually what is the purpose...????

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up some code to the `open` event of the dialog that will fire right before the dialog appears. In this code you can query the selected option and write it to the dialog:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'eventoid'); ?>
<div id="evento">
 <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'eventoid',CHtml::listData(Evento::model()->findAll(),'id', 'designacao'),array('prompt'=>'Escolha','class'=>'required')); ?>
 <?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(Yii::t('evento','Novo Evento'),$this->createUrl('evento/addnewcom'),array(
                                    'onclick'=>'$("#eventoDialog").dialog({open: function(){ $("#selectedvalue").text($("#eventoid").val()); }}) .dialog("open"); return false;',
                                    'update'=>'#eventoDialog'
                                    ),array('id'=>'showEventoDialog'));?>
  <div id="eventoDialog">
    <span>Selected value: </span><span id="selectedvalue" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense to me, but how can I get the selected value from the dropDownList and pass it on your example. Can you give me an example in my case? <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'tipo',Lookup::items('Teste')); ?>  This is the field that I want as the selected value, how can I pass it to the dialog so that I can populate certain fields on that dialog based on this value.

Comment: As I wrote in the code above this is how you can get the selected option from a `select` field: `$(#tipo).val()` supposing the ID of the `select` field is `tipo`.